# Sharing ArcMap with router and simultaneously two or more than two users can data entry in attribute table?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have two computer, one router and I want to share ArcMap and simultaneously from two computer filling the attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to share ArcMap session between two computers. It is possible to run ArcMap on Citrix, however, the session is per user only so there is basically no way to modify the map layers open in a particular ArcMap serssion simultaneously without actually starting another session of ArcMap and editing the very same layers (provided that the data source layers are coming from support multiuser editing).

If you require multiuser editing, but do not have multiple ArcGIS Desktop licenses, you could build custom desktop/web applications that are capable of editing your geodata stored in a format that supports multiuser editing that happens in the same time. There are quite a few libraries and frameworks that you could take advantage of.

Your best open-source option would probably be QGIS Desktop app with the PostGIS DBMS in the backend. Your ArcMap user(s) would also be able to see and edit the PostGIS database tables as QGIS users are editing them, so this could be pretty handy.

Comment: +1 but be careful you don't oversell the ArcMap & QGIS editing the same PostGIS data, it is possible **but** there's a lot more involved with editing PostGIS data from the ArcGIS side than just adding a connection **and** QGIS users will not be able to *see* the ArcGIS edits straight away... I've been in the situation of having Esri and QGIS editors with PostGIS and having to clean up the mess.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, thanks for the comment! I've done just simple tests and it worked well.. a bit naive of me! ;)

Comment: The marketing material and posts around the web sound good and with a quick play everything seems to click together it's not until you undertake a large project and are left with a mess do you realise where the problems are; a caution from me, it's better to edit with *either* Esri or QGIS (including other platforms) and not to have a mix of editors. It's easier to build the tables and import the data with ArcCatalog but be sure to specify PG_GEOMETRY either in the configuration keyword or dbtune... but that's wandering off topic and casting gloom on a concise and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use ArcGIS Online and then import feature layer to your ArcGIS Desktop.
This has some minor issues as posted in [this Esri GeoNet thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/52860)

Comment: Another 'minor issue' is the cost, ArcGIS Online is not cheap and only has multi-user-editor capability if served by ArcGIS Server, Enterprise for sure and perhaps Workgroup... though the method you suggest has merit from  a *read only* perspective; I have tried a similar approach (experimentally) using Mapserver as WFS over local network and it wasn't detestably bad so the logic is worth a +1.